# Why/where is code requesting a specific version of a library?

Tags: linux, compilation

This is in Linux. I've got the source code for a small tool that I'm installing on some new hosts. I compile the code on the new hosts, but it complains about a missing library:

```
ldd code.so
libpcre.so.0 => not found
```

The new hosts have libpcre.so.1 installed. So here's my question: why is it not compiling against the .so.1 library? Why is it looking specifically for .so.0? I've searched the through source code and through a few of the header files that it `include`s but there's no reference to a specific version of the library.

The following document mentions "Programs, when they internally list the shared libraries they need". This seems to be heading in the right direction, but it doesn't elaborate on how or where a program would do this.

Comment: What about the make file(s)?

Comment: I'm not using any makefile to compile it. Just running gcc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking into this further, it appears that when a program is compiled and linked, the linker automatically inserts the soname of all the required libraries into the compiled binary itself:

```
objdump -p ip.so | grep NEEDED
NEEDED               libpcre.so.0
strings ip.so | grep pcre
libpcre.so.0
```

In my particular case, the program I was talking about requires the above shared object, which requires the pcre library with soname libpcre.so.0. So that's where the dependency is failing. Even though my new host has the `libpcre` library, it has a different soname (libpcre.so.1 instead of libpcre.so.0) and hence the failure.

What would be interesting is: does anyone know if there's a way to tell the linker to substitute a different soname instead of the one specified in the dependency list? Obviously this would not work most of the time (if the soname changes it's most likely because the new version is no longer backwards-compatible), but still would be worthwhile knowing how to do this, if possible.